# Why isn't my JS running?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, external

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Practice!</title>
<link href="../_css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This is my source for jquery (which I got from my text book)

```
<script src="../_js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">
</script>


<script src="javascript/hello.js">
</script>

<script src="javascript/fadeIn1.js">
</script>

<script src="javascript/igotit.js">
</script>


</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <p class="logo">JavaScript <i>&</i> jQuery <i class="mm">The<br>
      Missing<br>
      Manual</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="main">
      <h1>Fading In</h1>
      <p>Here I come!!!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="aside"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>JavaScript &amp; jQuery: The Missing Manual, by <a href="http://sawmac.com/">David McFarland</a>. Published by <a href="http://oreilly.com/">O'Reilly Media, Inc</a>.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what my external javascript files look like.   For my external files, would they just need to be the "`<script>`" part of the code or the whole entire "`<DOCTYPE>`" to "`</html>`"?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Fade In</title>
<link href="../_css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../_js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').hide().fadeIn(3000);
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <p class="logo">JavaScript <i>&</i> jQuery <i class="mm">The<br>
      Missing<br>
      Manual</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="main">
      <h1>Fading In</h1>
      <p>Here I come!!!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="aside"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>JavaScript &amp; jQuery: The Missing Manual, by <a href="http://sawmac.com/">David McFarland</a>. Published by <a href="http://oreilly.com/">O'Reilly Media, Inc</a>.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry, I am new to this and am having troubles.

Comment: Have you downloaded jQuery in the correct location? Also, what is the source of all of the files you have

Comment: Look at your browser's web development console. It has readable error messages.

Comment: Are the files being loaded correctly? Check the Net tab in the developer tools for your browser and make sure it's showing an HTTP 200

Comment: I suspect you haven't put jquery-1.7.2.min.js in the right place

Comment: if you're new to this, then I'd suggest starting off more simply. Why have you got so many external files? Start off simply, learn the basics, then build from there.

Comment: Why isn't my JS running? I dont know

Comment: I am taking a class, and this was the first assignment. I will check the error messages again, to see if I see anything.

Comment: What would be the propper place to download the jQuery?

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820)

Comment: *"What would be the propper place to download the jQuery?"* The jQuery website: http://jquery.com/.

Comment: Please read [ask] and use an informative title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your external files should only have JavaScript in them, so nothing that looks like

```
<this/>
```

should be in them. It looks like you just want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').hide().fadeIn(3000);
});
```

...in your fadein1.js. Likewise for the other JS files.

When you have the document open in your browser, press F12 for some useful messages to paste here if it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Is Jquery file in the right location? If you are not sure just use this link for jquery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```